# Tomcat server unavailable from JEE7

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have created a gradle webapp project in IntelliJ.

I have set Tomcat 8.5.6 to execute the project.

In file `webapp/WEB_INF/web.xml` i have defined a servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.anatoli.customer.service.Home</servlet-class>
</servlet>
</servlet-mapping>


@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class Home extends Application {

}
```

And I have a simple java class to show something

```
@Stateless
@Named
@Path("test")
public class Customer {

    @GET @Path("text")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getText() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

When I run the project, and try to call http://localhost:8080/rest/test/text -> I receive 404

But if I run http://localhost:8080, then I can see the index.jsp that is in webapp-folder -> tomcat is running

I need to use Annotations in my JEE7 Project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat is web container and not an application server.

So your:

- `@Stateless` does nothing
- `@Named` does nothing as well
- `@ApplicationPath("rest")`/`@Path` does nothing unless you've provided a JAX-RS implementation either as apart of your app or in `catalina-home/lib` (but given your problem - you didn't)

Have you considered trying out Apache TomEE ? It's Tomcat + JavaEE spec impl., so it should suit you better

Comment: thanks, but now i became: WARNUNG - "null OEJP/4.6" FAIL "Security error - [Ljava.net.URI; is not whitelisted as deserialisable, prevented before loading it, customize tomee.serialization.class.blacklist and tomee.serialization.class.whitelist to add it to not fail there. -Dtomee.serialization.class.blacklist=- -Dtomee.serialization.class.whitelist=[Ljava.net.URI; for instance (or in conf/system.properties)." - Debug for StackTrace

Comment: @anatoli Wll the message says it all, you have to whitelist it. Follow this tutorial: http://tomee.apache.org/ejbd-transport.html

Comment: tomee have not solved my problem. I became now 404 everywhere. I am newbe in web applications

Comment: Check the log files

Answer (score -1):

Go To Intellij's RUN->EDIT CONFIGURATION and ADD LOCAL TOMCAT and deployment war in the deployment section to run the project locally.